# Shapes that can tile convex regions with only certain numbers of copies

Tags: recreational-mathematics, convex-geometry, tiling

Define a shape with connected interior to be **n-convex** if n copies of it can tile a convex shape.

Define the **spectrum** of a shape to be the set of all n≥1 for which the shape is n-convex.

Is there a shape with spectrum {1,5}, {2,5}, {3,5}, or {4,5}?

https://erich-friedman.github.io/mathmagic/0499.html